# What is correct Native Library Path to use OpenCV in eclipse-ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv3.0, ubuntu-15.04

I have an issue in setting native library path for opencv in eclipse-ubuntu.i am using ubuntu 15.04.installed opencv 3.1.0 following this link http://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/
and add new library(OpenCV) in eclipse and set it's jar path as

```
/home/user/opencv-3.1.0/build/bin/opencv-310.jar
```

and native library path as

```
/home/user/opencv-3.1.0/build/lib
```

`lib` folder contains `.so` and `.a` files. But when i try to use Mat object it gives me error:here is **Main Method**

```
System.out.println("Welcome to OpenCV hhhh " + Core.VERSION);
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
Mat img=new Mat();
```

and here is screenshot of my code and console
[image]
it gives me error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()J
        at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
        at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:24)
```

if i use mat like this

```
Mat m1 =Imgcodecs.imread("/home/zed/Desktop/img.png");
```

then it gives me diff error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread(Imgcodecs.java:102)
```

am i giving right path for native library? If not then what is the right path for Native Library to use Opencv3.1.0 in eclipse-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

you should add

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

## Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  System.out.println("Welcome to OpenCV hhhh " + Core.VERSION);
  System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
  Mat m1 =Imgcodecs.imread("/home/zed/Desktop/img.png");
  Mat m2=new Mat();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i added this line System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);  but same error!!!

Comment: You added the .jar ? as External ?

Comment: yes i added opencv_java310.jar as external jar and also added OpenCV library from user library in my project properties

Comment: Actually  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()J
        at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
        at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:24) 

This error corresponds to adding the  System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); did you added it in the first before calling anything of opencv ?? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: i added screenshot in my question

Comment: The both error you said is the same thing that It is missing the native library ;/

Comment: I'm not sure but probably this can be a bug from opencv's side or you are doing something wrong sonewhere

Comment: what type of issue can be?

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong with your build or anything I just installed it again with the current repo on ubuntu n it works fine :/

Comment: But the error means that you get the jar right but it cant find the native libs :/ or u r not loading the native libs . Can you post a full screenshot of the error and code . I mean the whole eclipse

Comment: added full screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102224/discussion-between-shoaib-akhtar-and-arijit-mukherjee).

Comment: I dnt know how to chat zzz

Comment: If you run the jar application outside eclipse does it works? I'm having the same problem, but only under Eclipse Ide. 

I made a link of the library inside my jre/lib  to make it work
`sudo  ln -s /usr/local/share/OpenCV/java/libopencv_java320.dylib /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.xxx.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libopencv_java320.dylib`